# Make log output more precise (log4j)

Tags: logging, log4j

I have a log output with equal time stamps:

```
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [org...] TS YYY
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 2
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 3
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 1
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [org...] TS XXX
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [org...] TS YYY
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 2
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 3
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 1
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [org...] TS XXX
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [org...] TS YYY
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 2
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 3
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [com...] TS 1
22-11 12:23:23,023 INFO  [org...] TS XXX
```

How can I configure log4j to show more precise time stamps?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Log4j uses standard `System.currentTimeMillis()` under the hood, and as the name suggests, it's only accurate to a millisecond.

Comment: You're welcome. On stackoverflow, you thank by voting on/accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion pattern that we use for Log4j is :

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %C{1} : %m%n

which seems to give us correct timestamps.

If your timestamps still come out the same after using something like this then its quite possible that your program is simply that fast.

What I would recommend is to put a 1 second sleep after some of the messages just to force the program to slow down a little and ensure that it is actually timing correctly.